# Unable to access ES 6 function when rendered through innerHTML

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, es6-class

I have following html code

```
<html lang="en">
 <body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script type="module">
      import { WriteReview } from "./src/script.js"
      var inputElement  = new WriteReview(document.getElementById("placeholder"));
      inputElement.render();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In script.js have following code

```
export class WriteReview{
    constructor(element){
         this.rating ="5"
         this.element=element;
    }
    setChange(){
        this.rating = "3";
    }
    render(){
      console.log("inside render");
        this.element.innerHTML = `<input type="button" onclick="this.setChange()" value ="Click here" />`
    }
}
```

When I click the button, browser reports an error "TypeError: this.setChange is not a function". Why I can't access the function setChange() from my index.html, how to resolve this issue. Issue URL: https://playcode.io/1532407

Comment: the `this` in `this.setChange()` won't be an as yet uncreated instance of `class WriteReview` - so ... I would imagine more luck with `this.element.queryElement('input').addEventListener('click', this.setChange.bind(this))` - though, not sure

Comment: Use `document.createElement` to create a DOM element object and use the Javascript API to attach an event listener to it, then you have a chance of preserving the right context. Writing HTML and setting it with `innerHTML` is only useful for the simplest of cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of problems here.

First and foremost, within an `onclick` attribute, `this` refers to the element itself which obviously does not have a `setChange()` method.

Secondly, you won't be able to set the click handler to your `WriteReview` instance method because anything referred to in an `onclick` attribute must be present in the global scope.

Instead, create an element dynamically and attach an event listener, using an arrow function to keep lexical scope within the class instance.

```js
render () {
  const input = Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), {
    type: "button",
    value: "Click here",
  });

  input.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    this.setChange();
  });

  this.element.append(input);
}
```

Here's a demo showing it working...

```js
class WriteReview {
  constructor(element) {
    this.rating = "5"
    this.element = element;
  }
  setChange() {
    console.log("WriteReview#setChange called");
    this.rating = "3";
  }
  render() {
    const input = Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), {
      type: "button",
      value: "Click here",
    });

    input.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      console.log("[before] rating:", this.rating);
      this.setChange();
      console.log("[after] rating:", this.rating);
    });

    this.element.append(input);
  }
}

var inputElement  = new WriteReview(document.getElementById("placeholder"));
inputElement.render();
```

```html
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: Neat little bit of streamlining there with using `Object.assign` to create an element and initialise its properties all at once. I hadn't seen that approach before

Comment: @MarkHanna it's so verbose otherwise 

Comment: @Nest I've added a runnable demo that clearly shows it working. Perhaps try clearing your browser cache